# Horizontal images Slide up

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to load this 5 images in a way that when the first image slide up, the second one which is slightly slower, slides next(right side) to the first one, and the third next to the second one and so on.

The problem is they all slide up the same way as the first one and only when loaded they place in the desire position.

```js
$(window).load(function() {
  $(".img").show("slide", {
    direction: "down"
  }, 400);
  $(".img1").show("slide", {
    direction: "down"
  }, 500);
  $(".img2").show("slide", {
    direction: "down"
  }, 600);
  $(".img3").show("slide", {
    direction: "down"
  }, 700);
  $(".img4").show("slide", {
    direction: "down"
  }, 800);
});
```

```css
.img {
  display: none;
}

.img1 {
  display: none;
}

.img2 {
  display: none;
}

.img3 {
  display: none;
}

.img4 {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div style="height: 200px"><img class="img" src="http://placehold.it/200" />
  <img class="img1" src="http://placehold.it/200" />
  <img class="img2" src="http://placehold.it/200" />
  <img class="img3" src="http://placehold.it/200" />
  <img class="img4" src="http://placehold.it/200" />
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried using `setTimeout()` on each individual `.img`, doing that will make the animations happen at different intervals which might solve your problem

Comment: I didnt, however i think the problem is not the time intervals but the position. Hover the 'World' category on the nav of this site   'https://jannah.tielabs.com/demo/'  its load exactly the way i want.

Comment: Thanks j08691 for editing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how you can make that

```js
$(window).load(function() {
  $(".img").each(function(i){
    $(this).show("slide", {
      direction: "down"
    }, i * 800);
  });
});
```

```css
.containImgs{
  background : #000;
  padding : 5px 0px;
  overflow : hidden;
}
.img {
  display: none;
  float : left;
  width : 19%;
  margin : 0.48%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div class="containImgs"><img class="img" src="http://placehold.it/200" />
  <img class="img" src="http://placehold.it/200" />
  <img class="img" src="http://placehold.it/200" />
  <img class="img" src="http://placehold.it/200" />
  <img class="img" src="http://placehold.it/200" />
</div>
```

**Notes:**

- no need to use more classes while you can just use one
- no need to set the height of the div while you don't know the final height of the image
- you can change the `img` element in the example with `div` if you need that *I prefer to use inside div to make every thing clear when margin or padding the div content*

Here's another example if you want to wrap it in a div

```js
$(window).load(function() {
  $(".no_margin_or_padding").each(function(i){
    $(this).show("slide", {
      direction: "down"
    }, i * 800);
  });
});
```

```css
.main_container{
  background : #000;
  padding : 5px 0px;
  overflow : hidden;
}
.main_container > div.no_margin_or_padding {
  display: none;
  float : left;
  width : 19.97%;
  overflow : hidden;
}
.main_container > div.no_margin_or_padding > div.you_can_add_margin_or_padding{
  padding : 5px;
  background : red;
}
.img{
  width : 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div class="main_container">
  <div class="no_margin_or_padding">
    <div class="you_can_add_margin_or_padding">
      <img class="img" src="http://placehold.it/200"/>
     </div>
  </div>
  <div class="no_margin_or_padding">
    <div class="you_can_add_margin_or_padding">
      <img class="img" src="http://placehold.it/200"/>
     </div>
  </div><div class="no_margin_or_padding">
    <div class="you_can_add_margin_or_padding">
      <img class="img" src="http://placehold.it/200"/>
     </div>
  </div><div class="no_margin_or_padding">
    <div class="you_can_add_margin_or_padding">
      <img class="img" src="http://placehold.it/200"/>
     </div>
  </div><div class="no_margin_or_padding">
    <div class="you_can_add_margin_or_padding">
      <img class="img" src="http://placehold.it/200"/>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Note:** the width percentage should be `20` while you use 5 images `100/5 = 20` but the `show()` slide effect make the last div do to the bottom so I used `19.97` instead to fit the screen

Comment: Very helpful Mohamed! Thank you very much.

Comment: @user2375180 you're totally welcome .. but please be sure when you trying to use `%` on css do this with `div` not with `img` and don't apply any margin or padding to this div .. i'll try to make an example for you to let you got this point well

Comment: Yes, i will pay attention to that, also i changed the % of the margin in the  img class  to 1px, and it set the images really smooth. Thanks again!